# Priority queue ADT using array based heap

Tags: java, heap, adt, priority-queue

This heap class runs and doesn't cause any errors.  The problem I am having is when I remove from the heap and just print out the pri value of each Entry, I can see that they are not in order.  I am pretty sure that this is due to fact that the trickle up and/or the trickle down method is not working correctly.

This is my Heap which implements my primary queue class.

```
public class Heap<E> implements PriQue<E>{
private static class Entry<E>{
    int pri;
    E data;
    Entry(int p, E d){
        this.pri=p;
        this.data=d;
    }
    public E getData(){
        return data;
    }
}
Entry<E> [] heap;
int count;

public Heap(int size){
    heap= new Entry[size];
    count=0;
}

@Override
public void insert(int pri, E data) {
    Entry<E> newEntry = new Entry<E>(pri, data);
    heap[count]=newEntry;
    trickleUp(count++);
}

public void trickleUp(int idx){
    int parent = (idx-1)/2;
    Entry<E> bottom = heap[idx];
    while(idx>0 && heap[parent].pri<bottom.pri){
        heap[idx]=heap[parent];
        idx=parent;
        parent=(parent-1)/2;
    }
    heap[idx]=bottom;
}

@Override
public E remove() {
    E tmp = heap[--count].getData();
    trickleDown(0);
    return tmp;
}

public void trickleDown(int idx){
    int largerChild;
    Entry<E> top = heap[idx];
    while(idx<count/2){
        int lChild = 2*idx+1;
        int rChild = lChild+1;
        if(rChild<count && heap[lChild].pri<heap[rChild].pri){
            largerChild=rChild;
        }else{
            largerChild=lChild;
        }
        if(top.pri>=heap[largerChild].pri){
            break;
        }
        heap[idx]=heap[largerChild];
        idx=largerChild;
    }
    heap[idx]=top;
}

@Override
public boolean isEmpty() {
    return count==0;
}

}
```

Here is the primary queue class.

```
public interface PriQue<E> {
void insert(int pri, E data);
E remove(); // return null when empty
boolean isEmpty();
}
```

The keys for the Entrys are: 24,5,2,10,6,11

When I call remove and print out the keys, I get this: 2,6,5,11,10,24

My desired output should read: 2,5,6,10,11,24

Comment: Why would a class called `Heap` implement `PriorityQueue`? That doesn't sound too reasonable.  Also, Java has a built in PriorityQueue collection - why not use that?

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum right now I am trying to learn how to use different data structures without using collections.

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum did you find anything when you were looking at my code?